# OCAML Reverse List Explanantion

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, ocaml

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYZN.png)

I do not understand how to reverse this list I have created. I have it printing out correctly and a list created on the previous function. The issue is, whenever I read an example on how to reverse a list, I can never get it to work. I've tried using List.rev l 0 and I get different errors. I am frustrated, because I think it has to be easy, but I am so unfamiliar with this language and syntax that I am completely lost.

Comment: Can you post the piece of code you tried? Did you check the List module documentation? https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

Comment: Please never post code images here in `Stackoverflow`. This is the violation of the guideline. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

If you look up `List.rev` in the manual at https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/api/List.html you'll see that it has the following type:

```
'a list -> 'a list
```

This means that you pass it a list (of any type) and it returns a list of the same type.

You say you called it like this: `List.rev l 0`. Why did you pass the `0`? You can see from the type that `List.rev` has just one parameter.

As you say, it's not difficult to reverse a list; it's a fundamental operation:

```
# List.rev [1; 2; 3];;
- : int list = [3; 2; 1]
```

If you'll forgive me for a side comment, I suggest you try to be patient. It eventually pays off to learn something about languages that aren't like the ones you already know.